# Getting the data from the program to GridView in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to post the data from the program, that is Id, FirstName and LastName to a grid view. I don't the grid at all. I crated the grid. Thanks for the help.

What I have tried:

```
 If results.Rows.Count > 1 Then
 Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataItem(_Id, _FirstName, _LastName)

 If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
 GridView1.DataSource = ds
 GridView1.DataBind()
 End If
 End If
```

It doesn't work. I don't see the table when I run. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend stepping through your code with the debugger.

Comment: How doesn't it work?  Error messages?  Does it reach `GridView1.DataSource = ds`?

Answer (score 0):

please go through: "GridView Control In VB.NET"

```
Private sqlDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private sqlConnection As SqlConnection
Private dataSet As New DataSet()
Private sqlCommand As New SqlCommand()

Public Sub BindData()
    sqlConnection = New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "Select _Id, _FirstName, _LastName from YourTableName"
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection
    sqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
    sqlConnection.Open()
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet
    GridView1.DataBind()
    sqlConnection.Close()
End Sub
```